# Smoothly unify paths with Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, vector, path

Essentially, what I would like is to unite nodes of different paths. With closed nodes, this is not possible as far as I know. So I would like to know if there is a way of unifying several paths in a way where no irregularities are seen. Here are some illustrations:

**fig1.** Objects I used and then transformed into paths.

**fig2.** Moving and adjusting paths in order to have a smooth shape with no irregularities. You can see irregularities in this picture on the left and right extremities.

**fig3.** After a while of node adjustment, I managed to obtain a smoother union of the three paths before doing path>union and obtaining a single path. *(The bottom irregularity is desired. These are meant to be shorts... eventually)*

**I would like to know if there is a more practical way of obtaining this result without having to move the nodes to simulate that all three paths are smoothly unified.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your goal simply to produce a symmetrical shape like that of fig.3?  If so, I wouldn't do it this way.  Much easier to draw one side of the shape with the Bézier tool, copy paste and reflect it, have the two pieces snap together, and then unify. [See example](https://imgur.com/a/xWSsIlB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an infinite number of ways to fade the gaps between these shapes and combine them to one. None of them is the magic one and only right way which is right and will stay right without anyone's opinions.

You have already got in a comment a method to get a symmetric result by drawing+duplicating+reflecting+combining the shape which looks right for you. No already existing Inkscape filter can guess what's the right transformation for you, but a competent programmer could write one. I guess his bill would be somehow bigger than the cost of applying the node tool few times.

If drawing and generating a new filter are not allowed for some reason you can try this:

[image]

1. the shapes to be combined in their right places and ungrouped
2. The shapes are combined with Path > Union and effect Path > Dynamic offset is applied (=dragged to bigger size until all gaps are filled)
3. To get an ordinary path the effect is fixed by applying Path > Object to Path and the shape is scaled to the wanted size.